# how to delete folder in dos console without list all contents deleted?

Tags: dos

In windowsxp, I use "del /s /q myfolder" to delete a big folder. It will list all files and folders being deleted. is there a way to avoid that long display list?
thanks,

Comment: I hate to be pendantic, but the command line in XP is not DOS.

Comment: @Andy: Don't hate it. The world needs more pedantic programmers.

Comment: @Heinzi: LOL.  I suppose I could think of it as being "detail-oriented".

Comment: @Andy: Did you mean command.com or cmd.exe? :) j/k ...

Answer (score 7):

```
rmdir /s /q myfolder
```

Answer (score 2):

or <strike>rmdir</strike> `del /s /q myfolder > nul`

Which is the equivalent of the Unix/Linux's `/dev/null` which throws away any outputs as they are redirected to a black hole of a bit bucket...

**Edit:** Thanks ***Heinzi*** for my stoopid error....I have struck out the rmdir and replaced it with `del` :)

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: You probably meant `del /s /q myfolder > nul`? rmdir does not produce output anyway...